# In an $n\times n$ grid with diagonals, how to count number of paths along the diagonals?

Tags: combinatorics, geometry, graph-theory, combinatorial-geometry, percolation

Given an $n\times n$ grid, with two diagonals in each unit square.

I am interested in the number of (directed) paths or walks from one side of the grid to the opposite side, walking along the diagonals. (Not walking along the grid lines of the base $n\times n$ grid.)
The restriction is that, for each individual path, you can walk on each diagonal only one time.

How many such walks are there?

(1) I have started to work on a solution, but I ran into a wall when I considered that you can also walk sidewards-backwards, and in loops, which adds a huge number of possibilites.

(2) Another approach I tried is to think of it in terms of two overlayed grids, i.e. the base $n\times n$ grid and then a second one which is turned by $45°$ and shifted, and compressed by $1/\sqrt2$, to represent the diagonals. But I had difficulties with the non-overlapping boundaries of these two grids.

(3) Maybe there is a simple, ingenious approach that I am completely overlooking. For example, I was thinking two paths are different when they differ by at least 1 diagonal. So maybe it comes down to just counting $1\times2\times3\dots$ and then multiply by the number of different starting points. But it did not lead me to a solution either.

I would be very grateful if someone could help me with the solution or point me to a reference.

Comment: What are the first couple terms of the sequence? (Have you checked the OEIS?)

Comment: I would say that this is a very hard problem when $n$ is more than about $20$.

Comment: Results from algorithmic search, for $n=1$ to $7$: $\{2,6,26,208,5342,265300,75760674\}$ (Yes, that is over 75 million for $n=7$, nevermind counting $n=20$ @TonyK)

Comment: @Daniel Mathias, Vepir, and TonyK, thanks to all three of you for looking into this! I am struck that the number goes up so quickly. I think this is why I got stranded in my first approach. --One question for clarification, when you did the algorithmic search, did you walk from left to right or additionally also allow walks from top to down?

Comment: @DanielMathias: Yes, I confess I forgot to square $n$.

Comment: All paths started at $(0,y)$ for $0\le y\le n$ and end when $x=n$, i.e. left-to-right only.

Comment: @Claus: it's much bigger than factorial growth, which is only $\{1,2,6,24,120,720,5040\}$ after all.

Comment: @TonyK you are right! Thanks a lot.

Comment: @DanielMathias I just wanted to inform you about this conjecture https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3689297/782412 which is a related topic but not exactly the same